# real life example of dom javascript for begginers

Tags: javascript

i need to know some practicals and beginner-friendly real-life applications of JavaScript?
or simple projects to practice of dom and javascript?

don't know much more about JavaScript so that i can start practicing the js on dom

Comment: https://roadmap.sh/javascript

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'll recommend you this free course : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp

Even for a non english, it's easy to understand.
Welcome in DOM and JavaScript

David